# Build query to INSERT multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to `INSERT` more than one rows into `MYSQL`.

I am trying to build my query in this way, In the end I have to remove the COMMA in the end of query.

WHat is the better approach to achieve this(or in less lines of code)

```
$file_user_group_map_query = "INSERT INTO file_user_groups_map ";

foreach ($user_groups_selected as $file_user_group_map) {
    $file_user_group_map_query .= "VALUES('',$file_id, " . $file_user_group_map . " ), ";
}
```

Comment: Use the function `implode`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$file_user_group_map_query = "INSERT INTO file_user_groups_map VALUES";

foreach ($user_groups_selected as $file_user_group_map) {
    $insert[] = "('',$file_id, " . $file_user_group_map . " )";
}
$file_user_group_map_query .=   implode(",",$insert);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$maps = array_map(function($m) use ($file_id) {
        return $file_id.",".$m; 
    }, $file_user_group_map);
$file_user_group_map_query = 
    'INSERT INTO file_user_groups_map VALUES('.
    implode ( "),('',  $maps ).
    ')';
```

Alternatively:

```
$maps = array_map(function($m) use ($file_id) {
        return "($file_id,$m)"; 
    }, $file_user_group_map);
$file_user_group_map_query =
    'INSERT INTO file_user_groups_map VALUES '. 
    implode ( ",'',  $maps );
```

Documentation:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php